# relation "django_content_type" does not exist during CI tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci, drone.io

I am hitting `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist` error during CI builds:

- https://travis-ci.org/VeggieSailor/vegbasket/jobs/91277871
- https://drone.io/github.com/VeggieSailor/vegbasket/119

  however I have migrations in place, I think:
- https://github.com/VeggieSailor/vegbasket/tree/nomigrations/vegbasketapp/vegbasketapp/vsdata/migrations

and `./manage.py test` locally works. Algo logs shows that migrations from contenttypes have been applied, I am clueless.

I am using django 1.8.7 dev from github because I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8.7/ that in 1.8.7 there are fixed some migrations related bugs. However, same bug appear with 1.8.6.

Comment: Build appears clean now. Is this fixed?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make incorrect import.

Comment: How did you resolve it? I'm hitting the same issue launching CI tests. What was your incorrect import? @bluszcz

Comment: @castledom04 I think here is solution for particular case
https://github.com/VeggieSailor/vegbasket/commit/548ff58e1e3aabd4a5813d6321c5a9bd9e09de5d#diff-9e88d85b119434b1d06b4a52f331baaeL8